# $firebaseSimpleLogin and session without re-login

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using $firebaseSimpleLogin to log into Firebase using email/password.

It is working rather well when I log in using email/password, I could see sessionkey being saved automatically as a cookie.

However, would like to remember the log in such that user only have to log in once.
So I included {rememberMe: true} during auth.

How do I check if the session is still alive at the beginning of the page being loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question, I assume you're using Angular JS.

You can execute a `run` block on your main module, which is run everytime the page is loaded. I don't know much about Angularfire, this is the code I'm using on a hack day project to check auth and redirect to the login page if needed.

`FirebaseRef` is a wrapper that points to my Firebase instance.

This also makes sure that the `currentUser` object is available in all scopes.

```
var minib = angular.module('minib', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

minib.run(function($rootScope, $location, $firebaseSimpleLogin, firebaseRef) {
  $rootScope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef());
  $rootScope.auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      $rootScope.currentUser = user;
    } else {
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks !!  $getCurrentUser is exactly what I am after.  Was  using $rootScope.auth.user but kept getting null.

Thanks again. saved me hours and hours :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, happened to be getting my feet wet with AngularFire too =)