# Firebase simpleLogin not working properly

Tags: angularjs, session, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to make a login session persist upon a page refresh but I'm not being successful in this matter. I took a look at this solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23165006/4054974) which uses the `$firebaseSimpleLogin` service to maintain a login session.

From that solution all I've done is basically deleted his wrapper that points to the Firebase instance, replaced it with my own `var ref` and put it as an argument of the `$firebaseSimpleLogin`. I also implemented array notation since I've done it with my controllers as well.

However, this function isn't even being executed because when I run the code it  throws this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseSimpleLoginProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseSimpleLogin
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this? I can't see anything wrong with my injections like the error is telling me.

```
var pieShopApp = angular.module('pieShopApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'firebase']); 

var ref = new Firebase ('https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/users');

pieShopApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$firebaseSimpleLogin', function($rootScope, $location, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
    $rootScope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
    $rootScope.auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
    } 
    else {
      $location.path('/pies/login');
    }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: That post uses a specific (and somewhat outdated) version of AngularFire. This steps might not work on the most recent version, which is what you might/should be using. You might want to try following the steps in Firebase's own documentation for AngularFire: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication

Comment: Might not = WILL NOT work in the most recent version, which is also the answer to this question.